# Auto-generated encryption keys in .NET

Tags: .net, cryptography

One can use Rijndael or RC2, providing null value for a key parameter:

```
        var r = new RijndaelManaged();
        var encryptor = r.CreateEncryptor(null, null);
```

Algorithms in subject will generate random key then ([first](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rijndaelmanaged.cs,65) and [second](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rc2cryptoserviceprovider.cs,112)). This contradicts a little with msdn, which [says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9df14hc(v=vs.110).aspx) that key or iv should not be null. (Probably, it worked this way in the past, and key generation is later addition).

What is a rationale for using such a random key? Obviously, we generate some irrecoverable gibberish, as soon as generated key is unavailable in the created encryptor, so we're unable to decipher it.

Test case code:

```
        var r = new RijndaelManaged();

        // encryptor 1
        var encryptor = r.CreateEncryptor(null, null);

        var inp = new byte[encryptor.InputBlockSize];
        for (byte i = 0; i < inp.Length; i++)
        {
            inp[i] = i;
        }
        var outp = new byte[encryptor.OutputBlockSize];

        // transform 1
        encryptor.TransformBlock(inp, 0, inp.Length, outp, 0);

        // encryptor 2, same parameters
        var encryptor2 = r.CreateEncryptor(null, null);
        var outp2 = new byte[encryptor.OutputBlockSize];

        // transform 2
        encryptor2.TransformBlock(inp, 0, inp.Length, outp2, 0);

        Assert.AreNotEqual(outp, outp2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I generally use the fact that it creates a random key to create a new key, but then save the key that I used when encrypting so I can decrypt.

One thing you can do with this is generate a random key to encrypt some data, then encrypt the random key using an RSA public key and store the encrypted symmetric key with the data. Then you just need the secret key to decrypt the data. The advantage is that symmetric encryption is faster than the public/private key. You use the RSA key to encrypt a small amount of data and the symmetric for the larger data.

**Edit:**
You can capture the key if you just change your code a little and use the parameterless `CreateEncryptor`.

```
var rand = new Random();
var r = new RijndaelManaged();

// Store the key and IV (you need both to decrypt)
var key = r.Key;
var iv = r.IV;

// This will create the encryptor using the key and IV above
var enc = r.CreateEncryptor();

var inp = new byte[enc.InputBlockSize];
rand.NextBytes(inp);

var outp = new byte[enc.OutputBlockSize];

enc.TransformBlock(inp, 0, inp.Length, outp, 0);

// To ensure that we have new keys, create a new Rijndael object
var r2 = new RijndaelManaged();
var enc2 = r2.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);

// Another option would be to set the key and IV of r2 and call the
// parameterless CreateEncryptor
var r3 = new RijndaelManaged();
r3.Key = key;
r3.IV = iv;
var enc3 = r3.CreateEncryptor();

var outp2 = new byte[enc2.OutputBlockSize];
var outp3 = new byte[enc3.OutputBlockSize];
enc2.TransformBlock(inp, 0, inp.Length, outp2, 0);
enc3.TransformBlock(inp, 0, inp.Length, outp3, 0);

if (outp.SequenceEqual(outp2) && outp.SequenceEqual(outp3))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Equal");
    Console.WriteLine("Key: " + Convert.ToBase64String(key));
    Console.WriteLine("IV: " + Convert.ToBase64String(iv));
}

enc.Dispose();
enc2.Dispose();
enc3.Dispose();
r.Dispose();
r2.Dispose();
r3.Dispose();
```

Comment: The last paragraph describes a [hybrid cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - Thanks!  I could not think of the terminology at the time I wrote this.

Comment: I see your point, but in my case, the newly generated key is not available.

Comment: @mikalai - I have updated my answer showing you how to store the key and IV so that you can reuse it.